# System.IndexOutOfRangeException C# -> for-loop error

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
double breite = new double();
breite = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 20;

rectA = new Rectangle();
rectA.Width = breite;
rectA.Height = 200;
rectA.Fill = greY;

Rectangle[] smallRect = new Rectangle[16];

for (int i = 0; i < (breite)-20; i++) {
 smallRect[i] = new Rectangle();
 smallRect[i].Width = 100;
 smallRect[i].Height = 100;
}

Content.Children.Add(progBar);
Box.Children.Add(rectA);
Box.Children.Add(smallRect[16]);
```

This code ist for a Windows Phone 8.0 Application. There is always a System.IndexOutOfRangeException, but I don't know why.

Sorry for this Question but I've googled a lot, but haven't found an anwer yet. I know that this is a very simple Question for you, but I'm new to C#.

This is a Screenshot of it 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51974164/public/Code5.JPG

Comment: Well presumably `breite` is more than 36... so `i` ends up being more than 15. Why are you *assuming* that the ActualWidth will be 56 or less? (And did you really mean to subtract 20 in two different places?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop index should probably be dependent on the collection you're looping over.  In this case, we have an array of `Rectangle` of length 16 (max array index of 15), but you're looping over what appears to be pixels?  Try changing your loop logic to go to the upper bounds of the `smallRect` array.

```
Rectangle[] smallRect = new Rectangle[16];

for (int i = 0; i < smallRect.Length; i++) {
 smallRect[i] = new Rectangle();
 smallRect[i].Width = 100;
 smallRect[i].Height = 100;
}
```

The above should work, however, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

I also noticed on the last line you try to access `smallRect[16]` which is undefined, since the maximum array index is 15 (because length is 16). If you just want the last entry in the `smallRect` array, consider using `smallRect.Last()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new array with 16 slots:

```
Rectangle[] smallRect = new Rectangle[16];
```

The longest for-loop you can do then is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { }
```

The `(breite)-20` is greater than 16, which is why your loop gives the the `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`-error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but a potential Gotcha for those coming from other languages like Java is when **you iterate over multidimensional arrays!**

```cs
// 2 dimensional array of strings
string [,] matrix = new string[,] {
  { "Hello", "Goodbye" },
  { "Foo", "Bar" }
};

// WONT work (Length is the number of elements in the entire matrix, not just 
// the number of rows)
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine("Key: " + matrix[i][0]);
} 

// this WILL work (you are requesting the length now of only 1 dimension: the # of
// rows)
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++) {
  Console.WriteLine("Key: " + matrix[i][0]);
}
```

Use [Array.GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) instead if you want to iterate over just 1 dimension at a time.